Is there a closed form for the following integral?
I want to find a closed form of the following integral:
$$
I \equiv \int_{0}^{R}\frac{b\operatorname{J}_{1}\left(ax\right) \operatorname{J}_{0}\left(bx\right) + a\operatorname{J}_{1}\left(bx\right)\operatorname{J}_{0}\left(ax\right)}{ab}\,{\rm d}x
$$
where $\operatorname{J}$ are Bessel Functions of the First Kind.

I used some properties, but it did not work.
I am wondering if this can be converted to a form of the Lommel's Integrals, but
the orders of the Bessel Functions are not the same.

